# How to connect laravel websock on live server -

Tags: laravel

https://websocket.shaapshoop.com/public/laravel-websockets
I m trying to connect websocket using laravel -
when i connect it give me **Channels current state is unavailable** On local host i run this it connect and event fire .. but on live server it is not working

My Connection setting in Config=>broadcasting.php file
'connections' => [

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            //'useTLS' => true,
         //   'encrypted'=> true,
            'host' => 'websocket.shaapshoop.com',
            'port' => 6001,
            'schema' => 'wss'
        ],
    ],
```

Guide me about this how can i run laravel websock on live server

I m try to connect but failed ..
I want to connect laravel websock so that event can fire